# python numpy.where function for lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, where-clause

I have a python program with two lists that look like the example below:

```
list1=["a","b","c","d"]
list2=[0,1,1,0]
```

Is there a elegant way to create a third list, that contains the elements of list1 at the position where list2 is 1? I am looking for something similar to the numpy.where function for arrays or better the elegant way:

```
array1=numpy.array(["a","b","c","d"])
array2=numpy.array([0,1,1,0])
array3=array1[array2==1]
```

Is it possible to create a list3 equivalent to array3, containing in this example "b" and "c" or do I have to cast or to use a loop?

Comment: Why not simply use `array3.tolist()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension here.

```
>>> array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> array2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> [array1[index] for index, val in enumerate(array2) if val == 1] # Or if val
['b', 'c']
```

Or use,

```
>>> [a for a, b in zip(array1, array2) if b]
['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) does.

```
>>> list1=["a","b","c","d"]
>>> list2=[0,1,1,0]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.compress(list1, list2))
['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following list comprehension:

```
[j for i,j in enumerate(list1) if list2[i]==1]
```

Which for your example gives:

```
['b','c']
```

Building a `get_val_where` function:

```
def get_val_where(list_val, list_where, val):
    return [j for i,j in enumerate(list_val) if list_where[i]==val]
```

To use like `get_val_where(list1,list2,1)`